# Disable ARC in Xcode project

Tags: xcode, automatic-ref-counting

How can I disable ARC in an Xcode project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create yourself a new project
2. Go to project settings, click the *Target* on the left
3. Click *Build Settings* along the top
4. Below that click *All* then in the search box type: automatic reference
5. One build setting should now be showing, change the *Yes* to *No*

Your project is now MRC, explore away! HTH